# Drag and drop in Nautilus sometimes does not work

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, mouse

I split nautilus window, open different folders in each part and then drag a file from folder on the left to the folder on the right in order to move it. Usually this works ok, but sometimes drag is cancelled and nothing happens.

I use standard optical mouse. I haven't been able to reproduce this bug reliably yet. Any ideas?

Comment: may be you are doing for protected files/locations

Comment: No I don't. What I usually do is that I repeat the drag more slowly and suddenly it works.

Answer (score 1):

While dragging a file/folder to another folder,you should wait till the icon of destination folder changes from this:
[image: normal]
to this:
[image: open]
Note that your icons may differ depending on your theme,but the idea is,you should wait until the destination folder responds to your drag.